# How do I get the size of a dictionary in julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

How do I get the size of a Dictionary in julia? `size()` throws an error.

```
julia> d = Dict(:x => 1, :y => 2)
julia> size(d)
  MethodError: no method matching size(::Dict{Symbol,Int64})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `length()`.

```
julia> d = Dict(:x => 1, :y => 2)
julia> length(d)
  2
```

The reason that `size()` doesn't work is that size is used to give the dimension of a container. From the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/):

```
size(A::AbstractArray, [dim])
```

> Return a tuple containing the dimensions of A. Optionally you can specify a dimension to just get the length of that dimension.

**and**

```
length(A::AbstractArray)
```

> Return the number of elements in the array, defaults to prod(size(A)).

The point with dictionaries is that they do not really have dimensions. You could of course represent them as one dimensional, but that would ignore the fact that the dictionary values can have "dimension", that are not necessarily uniform. For example, what dimensions should this dictionary then have? Two? Users might incorrectly assume they could access `dict[:a][1]`:

```
julia> dict = Dict(:a => 1, :b => [1, 2])
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Maybe we should add a `size(d::Dict)` method. Do you mind opening a issue (or even better a PR) over at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia?

Comment: I think `size` is for containers with a 'shape', like `AbstractArray`. What would the size of a `Dict` be, `(N,)`? Tuples don't have `size` either.

Comment: I made an issue at stackoverflow [#39783](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/39783). I'd like to make a pull request as well if people agree `size` should work on dictionaries as well. I'm sure that there are arguments  against it as well, but I think github would be a better place to discuss those. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I made an issue, and I think people there share the arguments DNF made.